# OpenLayers and OpenStreetMap as source, style issue using Angular

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

Map is displayed, but **zoom in/out buttons and logo of OpenStreetMap appears at the bottom of the map**. It seems like styling is not applied, but I'm importing ol.css (code in Angular 4), not sure what I'm missing here.
I've used this example: https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/basics/map.html

Section of my code (imports and init method):

```
//npm install ol
```

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/map';
import View from 'ol/view';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/osm';
import XYZSource from 'ol/source/xyz';
import proj from 'ol/proj';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/vector';
import Feature from 'ol/feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/point';
import Style from 'ol/style/style';
import IconStyle from 'ol/style/icon';
import { IAddress } from "./address";
...implements OnInit { 
    this.map = new Map({
            target: 'map-container',    
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                    //new XYZSource({
                    //    url: 
                    //    //'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    //    //'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
                    //})
                })
            ],
            view: new View({

                center: proj.fromLonLat([144.9, -38.1]),
                zoom: 7
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

OK! 
Just realised I can use scss and compile it as part of the project, so I've added ol.css into my scss folder and recompiled it...looks good now!